# Can't access my own repository after changing the name on github.com

Tags: git, github

So, I had an outdated repository name and wanted to update it. It was formerly just one little python file for a school project, but now I am using it to continue learning to code numerical methods on my own.

I changed the name on Github and then used the following command:

```
git remote set-url https://github.com/wcneill/numerical-methods.git
```

and then checked that I did it right with

`git remote -v`

But now when I try to push changes I get the following error:

```
git push
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I read elsewhere that this could due to some cached info that is now incorrect, but didn't understand what to do about it functionally. My knowledge of the command-line is limited to basic git commands.

Comment: Did you clone your repository using SSH? If so, could you try cloning using HTTPS to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Hi @LuVu, It is very possible that I did but not on purpose, since I don't really know the difference between SSH and HTTPS or what cloning is exactly. I'm really only familiar with making changes on my computer, committing and pushing them to github. Pretty brand new here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following command to change the URL of a git repository.

```
git remote set-url origin new.git.url/here
```

Also, clone your repos using **SSH** and not **HTTPS**, and they will be writable.

*Below is a screenshot of where you can get the SSH URL.*

[image]

Comment: That worked... I forgot to insert "origin" in the command git remote set-url ORIGIN url/goes/here